# Link multiple auth providers with firebase after logout as well

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, single-sign-on

I want to link multiple auth providers with firebase on login, I achieved that but once I logout I cannot link the account because I couldn't get the user to link

Comment: Can you explain it more clear way? Are you saying you can log out but can't use logins after logging out? @Maitri

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta Once I Logout using this method I couldn't link the user again
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        }

Comment: what error are you getting @Maitri? And also did you check the login details are saving in the firebase?

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta yes I can see the details in firebase but once I logout and try to login again I can't link the account

Comment: Are you getting any exception while logging in? If yes can you please post here @Maitri

Comment: I use facebook, phone, google sign-in verification using firebase. I never got such issue hence I am asking you @Maitri

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.linkWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)' on a null object reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192753/discussion-between-g-brahma-datta-and-maitri).

Comment: Are you using unlink method while logging out? @Maitri